# I have a music player project that is using XIB files, how to convert them to storyboard/Viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

I have a project that is a music player in XIB files but I would like to change it to storyboard, I keep having issues doing so, how can I convert this to storyboard instead of XIB?

https://github.com/lukagabric/LGAudioPlayerLockScreen

Comment: Expected Output ?

Comment: Would you make a start on the conversion yourself, and show us a specific code problem if you get stuck? This feels like a request for free work at present.

Comment: i did try the conversion i keep getting the following error message "Thread 1: Fatal error: NSCoding not supported".....here is the link to the converted files https://drive.google.com/open?id=13nCCuL8Nty-gwm0XBT4P2Rj9FIT0OWAf

Answer (score 0):

Xib files can't be converted to storyboard programmatically. You have to copy/paste controllers to your storyboard and replace navigation code with segues manually. But what profit do you expect?

Comment: I'm aware but I'm having difficulty having it working correctly when i do that

Comment: i keep getting a error message that says "Thread 1: Fatal error: NSCoding not supported"        here is the link to the converted story board files https://drive.google.com/open?id=13nCCuL8Nty-gwm0XBT4P2Rj9FIT0OWAf